# How to use a properties file with ScalatraBootStrap?

Tags: scalatra

I'm trying to use a properties file not included in the app but specify it as a Java option during invocation.

something like

```
java -Dconfig.file=run.properties -jar app.jar
```

I am looking for suggestions on  how can I send that property to ScalatraBootstrap when the app initializes.

Thanks

3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that this is only possible if I use

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
```